# How to compile asp.net website project as case sensitive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vs-web-site-project

Recently i have converted my **ASP.Net Website** to **ASP.Net Web Application**

Since it is a huge project, i am getting unexcepted errors

The very recent one is case sensitivity problem

When i try to compile, it compiles as case insensitive variables, thus no problem occurs

But when running, it runs as case sensitive, thus "**ambiguous match found**" error happens

How can i scan entire project to find such matches before they happen in the running environment? Ty

Comment: C# and javascript are case sensitive regardless of the type of app. Are you sure this is the issue?

Comment: Yes. I just that issue in my application. I have figured out the error in one page but it may be happening in more pages. Here example of my case : 2 times defined literal   <asp:Literal ID="lblPageTitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal>  <asp:Literal ID="lblPagetitle" runat="server"></asp:Literal> . it doesnt give any error but when i run and enter that page, it gives the error

Comment: Perhaps you should make it so you don't have conflicting names.

Comment: Honestly if I were you i would just fix all the errors. I cannot think of any other way.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, asp.net web forms control IDs are case sensitive as they act as access identifiers to the corresponding server control.
The associated html client id is generated using a logic that is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs).

If I guess correctly, you were deploying the web site through a copy-paste method instead of publishing. After the conversion, you no longer can copy-paste the project and you have to publish it (as it is a web application)

The reason you are getting the runtime errors is because you have many code behind page directives that point to the same partial class. To give you an idea, say that you have `PageA.aspx` and `PageB.aspx`. There should be two different classes on your project `Partial Class PageA` and `Partial Class PageB`. You have to check all your page directives to point to the correct code behind file that should point to the correct file and class.

Example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PageA.aspx.cs"
Inherits="PageA" %>
```

and

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="PageB.aspx.cs"
Inherits="PageB" %>
```

When the web site is deployed on the server as a whole project copy-paste, this does not affect the runtime as each page is compiled exmplicitly.

When you deploy a published web application, all libraries pre-exist inside the bin folder, so ambiguous defininitions exist inside the produced libraries files. Thus, on runtime, you get this error.

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: well when i try to publish, it publish without any error. but when i locally test it in debug mode and enter that conflicting names page, it throws error. so i wonder any way to detect such conflicting pages without navigating to each one of them :)

Comment: There is no "automated" way in vs out of the box to inform you of such kind of errors. You could create your own pre-build action that would scan all the `.aspx` and `aspx.cs` files in the project and display to the output window any findings related to such errors. Are those files so many at the end that you need an automation to find out? Just go one by one and correct / rename class name and definition.